# Passing data from array object to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have this array of objects. I have to create a new array with filtered results. I tried using the filter() method, but something doesn't go right, and the second array is empty.

**Code for the original array:**

```
 @foreach (var item in list)
        {
           @:newsObj.push({
            @:Id:@item.Id,
            @:Title: "@item.Title",
            @:FeaturedImage: "@item.FeaturedImage",
            @:DateFormated: "@item.DateFormated",
            @:Summary: "@item.Summary",
            @:Category: "@foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {@(cat.Title+" ") } "});

          
        }
```

And then code for filtering into the next one. Data filters based on the matching category:

```
newsObjFiltered = newsObj.filter(category => category.Category == selectedClass);
```

Comment: If calling `filter` on the array doesn't return any entries it means that no entries fulfill the conditions. Try to `console.log` the `selectedClass` values and manually check if the value exists in your array.

Comment: SelectedClass is curently a fixed variable with Category that exists, for testing purposes. Can the problem be that there are multiple categories in each Category: 
Example:  Category: "Event Webinar Infrastructure  ".  How does the filter() method actually compare data

Comment: The `filter` method in your example will compare two strings, as long as the `category.Category` is equal to `selectedClass` it should work as expected. If `selectedClass` is only one specific category, and you want to filter items that contain that category in the list, you don't want to compare strings instead check if the list of categories includes the other: `category.Category.includes(selectedCategory)`

Comment: includes() is not supported in IE, so that doesn't work for me. Should I write my own function instead for comparing? And if I understand correctly, the problem is in multiple categories then

Comment: Ideally you would build your data structure in such a way that `item.Category` was an array, as it's intended to contain multiple values. Then you could use `category.Category.indexOf(selectedClass) !== -1` to check if the array contains the given value across browsers.

Comment: I made the category as an array inside the newsObj.  @:Category: ["@foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {@(cat.Title+" ") } "]. How can I put each category in one index. Because right now they are all together:  Category: ["SQL Azure Infrastructure  "]

Comment: I'm not sure what templating system you're using, but something along the lines of: `[@foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {"@(cat.Title)," } ]` so that each category is a separate string in the array, separated by commas.

Comment: I am using  mvc .net core, so what you see there is Razor syntax. If I use your suggestion, the "@(cat.Title)," is just a string, it does not get me data from the model with foreach

Comment: What about `[@String.Join(", ", item.Category)]`

Comment: @:Category: @foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {[@String.Join(", ", @cat.Title)]} }); this gets me an error: Attributes are not valid in this context.

Comment: The `Join` already creates the list of all categories, you don't need the `foreach`. In any case if any other errors appear search online how to fix those and you'll resolve the main issue you were asking for here.

Comment: Hey , I solved it. With the help of indexOf(). I didn't have to create an array of categories, I just checked the string with indexOf(), and solved that with a simple IF sentence if the value != -1;  Thank you for all the help. Really appreciate it

Comment: With the help of indexOf() I could compare the selectedClass with Categories.            

       for (i = 0; i < newsObj.length; i++) {
    
                        if ((newsObj[i].Category).indexOf(selectedClass) != -1){
                            
                            newsObjFiltered.push(newsObj[i]);
                        } 
                }

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out.

Comment: I cant answer a question apparently, so I posted the solution in the comments 

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: Yes it was. I cant post solution   beacuse of my profile

Comment: Okay no problem you could share the way you resolved.

Comment: Solution is in the comments :) I cant post below beacuse of a ban that i got beacuse I deleted my question before